# Visual Studio 2010 add Outlook 2003 project template

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, office-2003, visual-studio-templates

I have installed Visual Studio 2010, and I want to create Outlook 2003 add-in program which add few buttons on navigating menu. I want to use some of the tempaltes provided by VS2010 ( at least in case of Office 2007 and 2010 provided) but there is no template for 2003 version. Is there a way to add it, or download somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no support for `Office 2003` addons in `Visual Studio 2010`. Only you can use Office 2007 or Office 2010 addons.

Comment: i was going to but the stackoverflow rule is to disable option of marking answer as "Answer" in 10mins. Now i am able to do this.